# Is there some way to have aws ecs run-task use networking defaults? Or even define networking settings in the AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I just want to execute a task in the default VPC and first/random subnet of a region for something like CloudFormation. For example if I don't specify the VPC when I create a resource like `AWS::ECS::Cluster` it just uses the default VPC.

Now that I have an ECS endpoint I want to start a Fargate task but I *must* explicitly pass a VPC id and subnet id and sg id to the command https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/run-task.html? Is there any way to have the command use the default VPC, first subnet and if possible the "default" security group?

Or will I have to script searching for the default VPCs ID, listing and getting a subnet id, and getting the default sg id?

Answer (score -1):

you just want to run a Fargate task, or want to create it first with default VPC and subnet?

If you just want to run a task, it may help you:

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster <cluster-name> --service <service-name>  --force-new-deployment
```

Comment: update-service will create the service if it does not exist?

Comment: no, it will just update the service. if you had made any changes in docker image or if your service is not running it will start.
To create a new service through CLI, you have to provide data in form of json. you can follow this blog.

https://medium.com/boltops/gentle-introduction-to-how-aws-ecs-works-with-example-tutorial-cea3d27ce63d

Comment: i dont need a service/elb or any of that, im just running a container and passing it an entrypoint/command. this is not a webservice so I dont think an ecs "service" is applicable to my use case